# TSQL find first and last day of fiscal month with variable dates

Tags: sql, date, reporting-services

My company fiscal calender has variable start and end dates for example,

```
Period 1 - 04-01-2013 to 04-26-2013
Period 2 - 04-27-2013 to 05-29-2013 
...
```

I have a date dimension in my SQL Server 2008 DB which stores all the fiscal month, and years.

It's easy to figure out MTD, YTD with calender dates but i can't seem to figure out the same for fiscal dates.

I am trying to create some calculated members based on our sales data.

So how can one get the first day of Period 2 for example.

Comment: Create a table for your fiscal periods with a start and end date?

Comment: Does your date dimension table have a single row for each calendar date?

Comment: Yes, it's a full date dimension. I am working with a relational model that connects date to few other tables for easy grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your date table has the required fields, your query might resemble this:

```
 select yourfields
 from yourtables
 join date on date.date = SomeOtherTable.date
 join (select min(date) mindate
 from date
 where fiscal_year = TheYearYouWant
 and fiscal_period = ThePeriodYouWant) temp on date.date = mindate
```

Note that a period number without a fiscal year will give you results from previous fiscal years as well.  You handle this either with a fiscal year field, or by giving your fiscal periods names like 'F2013/14 P1'.  Personally, I prefer a separate field for fiscal year.

**Edit starts here**

The query above gives you results for one day only.  If you want results for the current period, something like this will work.

```
 select yourfields
 from yourtables
 join date on date.date = SomeOtherTable.date
 join (select fiscal_year fy, fiscal_period fp
 from date
 where date = current_date) temp on date.fiscal_year = fy and date.fiscal_period = fp
```

Note that different db's have different ways of returning the current date, and you did not specify yours.